# Mapping styled JSX input elements is not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a component that maps input elements, which have a flag that determine if they should be inline or not. The problem is that I can't seem to get flex to work as expected. The `justifyContent: 'space-between` isn't working and it doesn't seem to be responsive.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Perhaps there a better/cleaner way to achieve this?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-wu-69w2r?file=/src/Form.js)

Comment: there is no `space-between` in your code. what is the layout you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Your style is not applied to common parent, so it wont work...

Comment: I've made the edit. I'm trying to align the two fields that have `inLine: true` inline with space-between, or looking for a better approach.

Comment: you are going to want to use the `space-between` on the flex container (i.e., the parent of the boxes - not on the boxes themselves)

Comment: I've tried that as well, something like `<div style={{ display: 'flex' }} ><Form fields={field} /></div>`, but this way it just maps all fields into it's own line. I'd like to conditionally also determine, if a field should be inline with another input field -- not map all fields into their own line

Comment: Its a CSS question, again, you need to apply 'flex', 'space-between' to a parent.

Comment: I've made an edit to the CodeSandbox with what you're suggesting, but it's displaying all fields in a line. Am I misunderstanding what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`justify-content: space-between` will tell the **flex container** to adjust the **flex items** in a way that they each have the same spaces in between. With that said, this property needs to be in the parent container.

```
<div style={flexContainer}>
  {fields.map(({ inLine }) => (
    ...
  ))}
</div>
```

As for the wrapping, you are going to want to use `flex-wrap` property. `flex-wrap: wrap` tells the flex parent to wrap the flex items when the content can no longer be contained. `flex-basis` in this context will behave like width (and will override it). You can use this property to tell the flex parent that this container with `100%` `flex-basis` should take up the entire row; you can give the inLine elements `0%` here so that `flex-grow` would determine it's size (i.e., specify how much of the remaining space in the flex container should be assigned to the item in respect to the other items inside the flex container). If you absolutely must have a "white space" in between the inline fields, use properties such as `margin` on the inLine elements.

```
const flexContainer = {
  display: "flex",
  flexWrap: "wrap",
  justifyContent: "space-between"
};

const style = inLine => ({
  display: inLine ? "inline-flex" : "flex",
  flexBasis: inLine ? "0" : "100%",
  flexGrow: inLine ? "1" : "0",
});
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-sammet-xp2on?file=/src/Form.js